# wrong size ActionBar on Android 2.3.7

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm use "android-support-v7-appcompat". This project migrated from eclipse (https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)
Compiles with eclipse project -- all fine, but after migrated has this problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz17z.png

Comment: moved  connection library in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems with ActionBar when I migrated from eclipse to Android Studio.

In the end I created a new project with Android Studio and copy-pasted all the codes and xml files into the respective folders. Everything worked afterwards.